# Keeping metadata and album art

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3, metadata, aac, album-art

I'm trying to convert aac 320kbps to mp3 320kbps but keeping album art and meta data bc I just want to convert the file extension. Is there a way to keep meta data and album art while converting?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/23741/how-to-prevent-ffmpeg-from-dropping-metadata

Comment: Welcome to SU. You're not giving very much information here. Please see [How to ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) in the [Help center](https://superuser.com/help) and [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1775007/edit) your question accordingly. I'd suggest something along the lines "I'm trying to convert ... on <Operating system version> and <ffmpeg version>. I'm using command `ffmpeg...`". The devil's in the details, the more you give the better answers you can expect.

Comment: Whar research have you done and what have you tried?